# JavaScript для Eclipse - плагин

Tags: javascript, eclipse, плагин

Подскажите пожалуйста годный плагин для Eclipse для работы с JS. Что бы были подсказки, что бы было видно функции подключенных библиотек. Аля Sublime Text только для Eclipse.

Comment: Нет такого. В Eclipse Neon, который будет конце июня, [обещали поддержку ES6](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JSDT/JSDT_Neon_Plan). RC [можете попробовать](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Neon/M7) уже сейчас. Eclipse - самая позорная IDE для web разработки, к большому сожалению.

Comment: @enzo А есть лучше IDE для разработки вебсайта с использованием JavaEE? Да, я делаю серверную часть на Java, поэтому и использую Eclipse.

Comment: Говорят, что годная fullstack IDE только одна - IDEA Ultimate.